# MERN deployment issue heroku

Tags: node.js, web, heroku, deployment, mern

I just started with backend and I am tying to deploy backend of my crud app but I am getting stuck for routes. After deploying on heroku I just get the part of app.get('/'). I can't find any router.get('/getData'.. or router.post('/updateData'..

here is the deployed heroku link:

for app.get('/'): https://vast-beyond-50574.herokuapp.com/

for router.get('/getData): https://vast-beyond-50574.herokuapp.com/getData

for router.post('/updateData'): https://vast-beyond-50574.herokuapp.com/updateData

Here is the code for backend server.js

````
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const Data = require('./data');
const API_PORT = 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
const router = express.Router();

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/backend');
let db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to the database'));
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));

router.get('/getData', (req, res) => {
    Data.find((err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
        return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
    });
});

router.post('/updateData', (req, res) => {
    const { id, update } = req.body;
    Data.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, (err) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
        return res.json({ success: true });
    });
});

router.delete('/deleteData', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    Data.findByIdAndRemove(id, (err) => {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        return res.json({ success: true });
    });
});

router.post('/putData', (req, res) => {
    let data = new Data();
    const { id, message } = req.body;
    if ((!id && id !== 0) || !message) {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            error: 'INVALID INPUTS',
        });
    }
    data.message = message;
    data.id = id;
    data.save((err) => {
        if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
        return res.json({ success: true });
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Deployed!');
});

app.use('/api', router);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${PORT}`));```
````

Answer (score 0):

You're using your router inside the `/api` route (`app.use('/api', router);`) which means all of those routes will be prefixed with `/api`. So, you should be able to visit `https://vast-beyond-50574.herokuapp.com/api/getData` and see your data. (However, I tried this and got a different error, which you will have to debug separately).

Comment: I already tried that but got error and tried lot to bug it out. Here's the error after `heroku logs --tail"` command:

`2020-01-26T22:49:13.592270+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /favicon.ico 404 0.675 ms - 150
2020-01-26T22:50:35.134043+00:00 app[web.1]: HEAD /api/getData - - ms - -
2020-01-26T22:50:35.130662+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=HEAD path="/api/getData" host=vast-beyond-50574.herokuapp.com request_id=5ea406e2-f4f9-47c5-bd34-422ace300816 fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
`

Comment: Looks like you're getting a timeout. My guess is that it's unable to reach your database.

Comment: Do you see "connected to the database" in your server logs?